# num2str with a specific format in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, formatting, floating-point

```
>> x = 14.021
>> num2str(x,'%4.5f')
```

I want to get this as a result:

```
0014.02100
```

But, MATLAB just answers me with:

```
14.02100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html). For example:

```
x = 14.021
sprintf('%010.5f', x)
```

Note that you don't need to use `num2str`.

The first argument to `sprintf` is the format specifier which describes how the resulting text should be displayed. The specifier begins with `%`, the leading `0` tells `sprintf` to pad the string with zeros. Loosely, the `.5` tells it to print five digits to the right of decimal point and the `f` tells it we want to format it like a floating point number.